# Chart.js Legend not showing

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to get my piechart to display its legend however I can't seem to get it right.

I've post my codes here:

```
var legend = mydoughnutChart.generateLegend();

$('#doughnutChart').append(legend);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mark5ahm/3k2be814/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with a latest update in jsfiddle.

```
var doughnutOptions = {
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mark5ahm/3k2be814/5/